# Make a metro tile for non Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, icons, windows-store-apps

Is there a way I can make a Windows Store App style tile for non Windows Store App applications? Kind of just like, a new icon for a non-metro app.

example:
I'd like to make a tile for chrome, and itunes.  Since they aren't Windows 8 apps yet, they don't have tiles. If you pin the program to Start, it looks blah... I'd like to make a full sized metro style icon for them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865

Enough said! It has the ability to do just what you want. Hopefully this helps others as well.

Comment: Can you include a short summary of that post in your answer? That way if the [link rots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) this SO answer will still be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a VS2012 metro app that simply opens up the chrome.exe process, and then customize the tile.

Comment: An app that did only this might have a hard time getting certified. If it's not going to go through the store then it might be enough.

Comment: I don't think he is doing this for certification...he is doing it for personal preference.

Comment: You're right, I'm just doing it so that I can enjoy my metro interface. Not going to publish the app.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to do this.
What i did so far is create a white simple version of the desktop programs i use.
Specify those as the icon for the shortcuts. Like this it looks a bit more like a metro tile but the tile doesn't have a fancy color ofc and the image is always downscaled.

I don't think you can create a Metro launcher app for your desktop apps.
I quote:

> All metro apps need to be certified, Only Windows 8 Enterprise can use uncertified metro apps. Windows 8 (Metro-style) app deployment. Domain joined PCs and tablets running Windows 8 Enterprise will automatically be enabled to “side-load” internal, Windows 8 Metro style apps, bypassing the Windows Store

Comment: I was able to confirm this on the MSDN forums too :(  Here's a link. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/6ec85fbe-beb2-45ea-96a1-d09c22aec58e/#b42f869e-2329-4ad8-8ff8-6b6e6528d8cb

Comment: there is a program called "obly tile" which can create custom tiles. It creates really crappy tiles, I don't recommend it at all. However, it is obviously possible for end users who don't have windows 8 enterprise to create custom tiles.

Comment: Moved correct answer to another answer since time has passed, and a more accurate answer exists..